# div border does not wrap around nested divs

Tags: css

I am having this problem with a layout I designed. The part in question is the div id="menu", where I styled

```
#menu {border-bottom:solid}
```

The border does not wrap around the nested content (another div and a ul menu), but instead sits above it. The example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Amct3/2/

Comment: You need to clear your floats inside the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the float after the "menu"

Add this code

```
#menu:after {
  content:"";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I need to remember that floats are removed from the flow, which appear like anomalies if not cleared. Why is "display: table" required for this to work?

Comment: Basically creates an table-cell that prevents a collapse

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats.

Add another div under the container with the style "clear:both"

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Got to admit, David's solution is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

you could just remove the "float:left" from "#menu ul" and instead give it "height:40px;clear:both;". will fix it.